# Get database access via Joomla dashboard

Tags: joomla

I've been given admin level access to a Joomla site, is it possible to see the database password via the dashboard? It's version 3.6.5.

I can see all the database settings in the global configuration menu but it's hiding the password.

I've never used Joomla before, I'm looking to move all the content across to a Wordpress setup. This can be done via a plugin but it needs the database details.

Comment: As far as I know the password is stored in configuration.php in the root of the www-folder. So if you have ftp-access: open that file and check all settings.

Answer (score 0):

The only place where Joomla stores the database password is the `configuration.php` file in the site's root directory. That file should not be accessible from a web browser, and due to security concerns, Joomla does not provide a way to show the content of the configuration file.

However, there are some options to get the credentials in question:

1. The best way to get the credentials is to ask the administrator of
   the site. If (s)he wants you to do the job you're talking about,
   (s)he'll happily give it to you.
2. Next best option is to access the filesystem of the web server via
   SSH or (S)FTP and look into the `configuration.php` file.
3. The least recommendable option is to install a file manager
   component on the Joomla site, which allows you to access the
   filesystem using your browser. You'll find such components in the
   [Joomla Extension Directory](https://extensions.joomla.org).

Comment: Thanks for the help but I managed to get it (see my answer). The previous developer had left and no one had access details apart from an admin account. A complete nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

With both hands tied I managed to get it... the theory had applied to Wordpress previously so I did the same thing. I managed to get to the configuration.php file by backing up the site and downloading the file.

I used [EJB](https://joomla-extensions.kubik-rubik.de/ejb-easy-joomla-backup), it was the only extension that would install due to the upload limit being so small (I didn't have access to that either!!!). I excluded all directories and files except the configuration file to ensure the backup was as small as possible. It then showed the password within the file.

I was then able to migrate all data from Joomla to Wordpress with the details. Job done.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code to see password of your database.
You can print this in your coded file.

```
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$password = $config->get('password');

echo $password;
```

Thanks.